# Hadoop and PiggyBank incompatibility

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to use `org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage` from `piggybank.jar` archive. I downloaded `pig trunk` and built piggybank.jar by following the instructions [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank). However, I get the error below when I use the MultiStorage class.

`Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected`

By looking [here](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/12asc6jt1a/error-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-taskattemptcontext-but-class-was-expected), it looks like there is a version incompatibility between the piggybank build and the hadoop version. But I am not able to fix this issue. I really appreciate any help on this (spent inordinate amount of time on this already).

pig.hadoop.version: 2.0.0-cdh4.1.0

> > hadoop version
>
> Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.1.0 Subversion
>   file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-ubuntu64-10-04/CDH4.1.0-Packaging-Hadoop-2012-09-29_10-56-25/hadoop-2.0.0+541-1.cdh4.1.0.p0.27~lucid/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r 5c0a0bddbc2aaff30a8624b5980cd4a2e1b68d18 Compiled by jenkins on Sat Sep 29 11:26:31 PDT 2012 From source with checksum
>   95f5c7f30b4030f1f327758e7b2bd61f

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not able to figure out how to build a compatible piggybank.jar, I found that a compatible `piggybank.jar` is located under `/usr/lib/pig/`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I used piggybank version 0.13 with Hadoop version Hadoop 2.4.0.2.1.5.0-695. It however worked when I used the piggybank jar in the location you mentioned -- /usr/lib/pig.

The additional observation I made is the piggybank jar in /usr/lib/pig is quite old and does not have XPath and other functions available. I believe new piggy jar has dependencies on later Hadoop version.